Trying to set up Outbound Email, but no Test Email is received. Why?
Our Association has implemented CiviCRM (version 5.75.2) in our WordPress site jemseggrandlakewatershed.ca .  We are trying to configure the CiviCRM Settings - Outbound Mail in the Configuration Checklist as shown in the screenshots below. The pop-up window says the email was sent, but it was never received.  We used the mail() option which, as we understand it, uses the PHP mail function.  We also tried the SMTP option, but this requests the SMTP server name and SMTP port name.  Can we get CiviCRM to send email messages from our jemseggrandlakewatershed@gmail.com email address?


Did you manage to sort out your email problem? I am trying to set up through my gmail account using these instructions (imap) https://civicrm.org/blog/dahndy/leveraging-civicrm-email-to-activity-processing-in-gmail and I had a similar problem - the emailing appeared to send, but wasn't actually received. If you have sorted it out - I would love to know how you did it!

You might have a look at this to see how to use the SMTP function with your gmail address? https://mailtrap.io/blog/gmail-smtp/
in combination with this: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/
